# Optimize large offset in select

Tags: postgresql, pagination, indexing, limit, offset

I have table

```
Users (user_id integer, user_name string, scores integer)
```

That table will contain 1-6 millions records. That has **indexes** on **user_name** and **scores**

The user will input his name and I should show him one page from that table, ordered by scores, that will contain him around other users.

I do it in 2 queries:

**First**:

```
select user_id from (
       select row_number() over (order by scores desc), 
              user_id 
       from users 
       where user_name="name" limit 1
)
```

**Second**:

```
select * from users limit 20 offset The_User_Id/20+1
```

than i get page, that contain my User around others.

But when user is in middle of table with millions record, I have offset 500000, that works slow, about 1-2 seconds, how to improve it?

Comment: Consider pre-generating the data as a materialized view that you refresh every few minutes.

Comment: Please show your actual queries.  Your first query is not syntactically valid in PostgreSQL, and if I make the mechanical fixes to it, it then doesn't do anything sensible.

Answer (score 0):

Offset itself makes your query slow. 
If you don't need a pure sql and can use a programming language to form the query, why not consider [Paging Through Results](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page)? ordering the second query by user_id and limit 20 for pagination needs instead of using offset.